# How do I fix error in resample function in R

Tags: r, mlr

When I run the code below, I get an error:

> Error in resample(learner = knn, task = diabestertask, resampling = holdout,  :
> Assertion on 'resampling' failed: Must inherit from class 'ResampleInstance', but has class 'function'.

Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
install.packages("mlr", dependencies = TRUE)
library(mlr)

data(diabetes, package = "mclust")
diabetestib <- as_tibble (diabetes)
summary(diabetestib)

diabestertask <- makeClassifTask(data = diabetestib, target = "class")
diabestertask
knn <- makeLearner("classif.knn", par.vals = list("k" = 3))

holdout <- makeResampleDesc(method = "Holdout", split 2/3, 
                            stratify = TRUE)

holdoutCV <- resample(learner = knn, task = diabestertask, 
                      resampling = holdout, measures = list(mmce, acc))
```

Comment: Your posted code has mismatched quotes in `method = 'Holdout"`. Is this a transcription error?  If not, it might be the cause of your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to holdout <- makeResampleDesc("Holdout", split 2/3, 
                            stratify = TRUE), but now the error is: "> holdout <- makeResampleDesc("Holdout", split 2/3, 
Error: unexpected numeric constant in "holdout <- makeResampleDesc("Holdout", split 2"
>                             stratify = TRUE)
Error: unexpected ')' in "                            stratify = TRUE)" 
Any idea whats still wrong?

Comment: You need the equals here: split **=** 2/3